# Azure Active Directory needs Admin Approval after setting prompt =consent

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory

In my application in Azure Active Directory I have added one of the Admin's consent required permission to the Graph API, let say `Group.Read.All`. I've clicked `Grant Admin Consent for ...`. If I hit `/authorize` endpoint as a User with the query parameter `prompt=consent`, I'll get the view that I need admin approval. If I hit the endpoint without any `prompt` parameter, everything works fine - I'm able to get a token with a proper scope. In the documentation I've read that `prompt` parameter determines only the visibility of the consent. Why it works like that?

Comment: You are asking for Azure AD to get consent again, and your app requires a permission that requires admin consent. Do you expect something different to happen?

Comment: @juunas So the user won't have a chance to see what permissions the application will have to act as they. Do you think this is the right behavior? I think that as soon as the Admin click ```Grant Admin Consent for ...```, the user should get a normal view with all permissions.

Comment: Right, it seems that AAD will always do full consent if you ask for it. This behaviour _is_ a bit confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding `prompt=consent`, [OpenID Connect says](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest):

> The Authorization Server SHOULD prompt the End-User for consent before returning information to the Client. If it cannot obtain consent, it MUST return an error, typically `consent_required`.

In the Microsoft Identity platform, this means that the end user will be *required* to provide consent, even if consent has been granted previously by the user or (in the case of work or school accounts, by an administrator on behalf of the user).

If the user is not authorized to consent to the requested permissions (e.g. because user consent is disabled or restricted), using `prompt=consent` will always result in a hard block for the user.

In most cases, using `prompt=consent` is *not* the best approach. There are typically three scenarios `prompt=consent` is considered:

1. **You've changed the required permissions**. The required permissions have changed (e.g. permissions have been added or removed), and the user needs to consent to the new set of permissions.
2. **You want to inform the user**. The app developer wishes to ensure the user is informed of which permissions the app will be authorized to exercise (even if an administrator has already consented on behalf of the user in question).
3. **You require consent from the user themselves, not an admin**. The app developer wishes to ensure the end-user themselves provides consent, independent of what an administrator may have authorized previously.

### If you've changed which permissions are required

**When the requested permissions are defined dynamically**

On [the v2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview), the `scope` parameter can be used to [dynamically](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#incremental-and-dynamic-consent) request a list of delegated permissions. For example, to request the `read` and `export` delegated permissions of the API identified by `https://api.example.com`:

```
scope=openid https://api.example.com/read
```

Azure AD will ensure that all the requested permissions have been granted, and attempt to prompt for consent for any permissions which have not yet been granted (and only for those). If the requested permissions have all been granted, the issued token will include all granted permissions (even if they were not specifically requested).

Generally speaking, when making use of the incremental consent capability of the v2.0 endpoint, `prompt=consent` should *not* be used. Azure AD will take care of prompting for incremental consent if needed.

**When the requested permissions are defined statically**

An app can also identify only the resource (i.e. the API) for which it is requesting an access token, the specific permissions being defined statically for the app. Using the v2.0 endpoint, this is done in the `scope` parameter, making use of [the special `.default` permission value](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#the-default-scope):

```
scope=openid https://api.example.com/.default
```

In [the v1.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-overview), this was achieved using the `resource` parameter:

```
resource=https://api.example.com
```

The list of required permissions is configured in a static list on the app registration. In the Azure portal, this list is under **Configured permissions** in Azure AD > App registrations > API permissions. In the unerlying [Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0) entity in Microsoft Graph (and in the [app manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest)), this is stoerd in the `requiredResourceAccess` property.

On receiving a request of this type (on either the v1 or v2 endpoint), Azure AD will check which permissions have been granted for the requested resource:

1. If *no* delegated permissions have been granted for the requested resource *OR* if `prompt=consent` is used, Azure AD will attempt to prompt for all the required permissions from the statically-defined list. This will include permissions for other APIs, if any are configured.
2. If *any* delegated permission has been granted for the requested resource, Azure AD will issue the token with all granted permissions. The `scopes` parameter *of the response* will include the list of permissions included in the access token.

Applications relying on statically-defined required permissions (i.e. `/.default` on v2 or `resource` on v1) should *not* use `prompt=consent` for every sign-in request. Instead, the application should:

1. Perform a sign in *without* `prompt=consent`.
2. Check the `scope` parameter of the *response*:

   - If the desired permissions are listed, no further action is necessary.
   - If not (e.g. if a new permission was added to the list of required permissions after the user initially consented to the app), *only then* should the user be sent back again, this time with `prompt=consent`.

This strategy ensures that users can sign in to an app when an administrator has consented on their behalf (e.g. because they aren't authorized to consent on their own), and only forces the consent prompt (or an escalation to an admin to consent on their behalf) when a new permission has been configured.

### If you want to inform the user

Using `prompt=consent` is not a good approach if the goal is to only *inform* the user of which permissions the application has been authorized to exercise (either by the user previously, or by an administrator on the user's behalf).

Instead, an application can use the `scope` parameter of the token response to construct the desired interrupt experience (e.g. after the user has been redirected back to the app and the token has been retrieved, but before continuing), informing the user of which permissions it has been granted.

### If you require consent by the user, not an admin

There may exist very specific cases when an application requires *user* consent for the requested permissions, and wishes to *not* accept  consent granted on behalf of the user by an administrator.

In this case, using `prompt=consent` in all sign-ins could be used, but there are  important caveats to consider:

- In many organizations, [user consent is disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent) or restricted. If users are not authorized to consent to the permissions configured for your app, they will not be able to use your application.
- The user will be prompted for consent every single sign-in, even if the user themselves already previously granted consent.
- Since this is a query parameter, a knowledgeable user could very easily intercept the request before it is made, and remove `prompt=consent` (and if consent was already previously granted, they will not be prompted for consent).

In this case, it may be better the app to implement a separate consent-granting experience *after* the user has signed in (similar to the "inform" scenario described earlier), separating the app's additional consent requirements from the consent experience provided by the Microsoft identity platform.

Answer (score 1):

> `prompt=consent` triggers the OAuth consent dialog after the user signs in, asking the user to grant permissions to the app.

Individuals accessing an app that requires at least one permission that is outside their scope of authority.

Admins will see the same prompt show the permission and will see an additional control on the traditional consent prompt that will allow them consent on behalf of the entire tenant.

[image]

Users will be blocked from granting consent to the application, and they will be told to ask their admin for access to the app.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/application-consent-experience).