# Azure AD - App Registration - Tenant Consent

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, registration

I have a question regarding a multi-tenant App Registration in Azure AD.  The first time a user logs in through the app it will ask him to grant his consent to access some of his data if necessary or ask an administrator to grant a tenant level consent.  This is just fine.

But what if a change is made to the App Registration (Logout URL modified for example)? Is it possible that the users that never used the app registration already will need to grant their consent or that a tenant administrator might need to give his consent again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your redirect URLs or logout URL will not cause the consent to be prompted for again.

Changing the configured permissions also won't cause users who have already granted consent to have to grant consent again (but the app will only have the permissions it had been originally granted).

Users will only be prompted for consent in the following situations:

- If your application dynamically requests a permissions which has not been granted (e.g. `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Read`, if *Mail.Read* has not been granted.
- If your application requests access to ".default" for a resource, and no permissions have been granted for that resource. For example, if you application requests `scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` and no delegated permissions for Microsoft Graph have been granted, the user will be prompted for consent (for all permissions configured in the app registration). If *any* permission for the requested resource have been granted, the user will not be prompted for consent.
- If your application forces user consent using `prompt=consent`. Don't do this—there is almost no situation where this is necessary. (Read a lot more on this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60151790/325697.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you modify properties such as **redirect url**, **permissions**, **logout url** and so on, you have to make admins from other tenant do the admin consent again to make it effective.

Using [admin consent url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent) is the quickest way:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Would have been great that before "saving" changes to app registrations the UI warns us that this would happen.  I can't see this anywhere.

Comment: No, this is incorrect. You do not need to get consent again when you update any of these properties.

Comment: The admin consent is needed to make the changes effective. Im not saying the admin consent will be prompted again.