# Random errors acquiring Microsoft oauth2 token via golang.org/x/oauth2

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I use the standard go library `golang.org/x/oauth2` to acquire an OAuth2 token from Microsoft users.

This is the oauth2 config I use:

```golang
return oauth2.Config{
    ClientID:     clientID,
    ClientSecret: clientSecret,
    Endpoint:     microsoft.AzureADEndpoint("common"),
    Scopes: []string{
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    },
}
```

This is how I get the redirect URL:

```
oauth2Config.AuthCodeURL(state, oauth2.ApprovalForce, oauth2.AccessTypeOffline)
```

And this is how I exchange the code acquired in my oauth2 callback to the oauth2 token:

```golang
oauth2Config.Exchange(ctx, code)
```

I use the same code for integrating with github, google cloud platform, bitbucket and digitalocean. It has been working fine for me and it does work with Microsoft but sometimes I **randomly** get one of the following errors:

> AADSTS90013 Invalid input received from the user

or

> AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.

And I don't understand what might be the reason. The first error potentially could be caused by some JS bugs in the Microsoft consent screen. The second error makes no sense – oauth2 lib sets `grant_type` value correctly, I search for this error and it says the issue could be in the incorrect encoding which should be `x-www-form-urlencoded` but I've looked up oauth2 library and confirmed that's exactly what it does.

Or maybe there's a timeout for a repeated acquisition of a token under the same user.

UPD: I get these errors during the exchange of a code to a token

UPD2: I started to get oauth2 errors randomly with other providers, such as DigitalOcean, the errors also happens during the code to a token exchange. Errors like this:

> ERROR STACKTRACE: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request
> Response: {"error":"bad_request","error_description":"invalid semicolon separator in query"}{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed."}
> could not get auth token

I've looked up values in my oauth2 config, it's all correct, the values however are not url encoded (I assume oauth2 lib handles this).

I've recently upgraded my go to 1.17.6

UPD3: I've noticed that my oauth2 configs both for DigitalOcean and Microsoft didn't have `AuthStyle` specified, so I've set it manually to `oauth2.AuthStyleInParams`. But this still didn't resolve the issue. After a few repeated attempts with DigitalOcean it started to randomly return the following error:

> Response: {"error":"bad_request","error_description":"invalid semicolon separator in query"}{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed."}

which I don't even think is a valid error, there's no semicolon symbol neither in the request URL nor the body

UPD4. It may sound stupid but when I restart my app (I run-debug it via GoLand) DigitalOcean oauth works just fine until I connect a Microsoft account via oauth2 (which also works fine), but then if I connect (reconnect) DigitalOcean account again then it just stops working ¯_(ツ)_/¯

UPD5. Below is the debug watch of `doTokenRoundTrip` function inside oauth2 library. The token exchange request returns 400 bad request

[image]

The request body:

> client_id=[redacter]&client_secret=[redacted]&code=e50e6dc91ec6b855becdef7a32cc4e28684851ccf385b2f6bb667ed6ec1172df&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fv1%2Fdigitalocean%2Foauth2%2Fcallback

The URL and the body both looks good to me. However this returns the following error:

> Response: {"error":"bad_request","error_description":"invalid URL escape "%\x9b\x06""}{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed."}

UPD6. Exchange request headers:

[image]

Comment: This is unlikely to have anything to do with your issue, but you probably shouldn't be using `oauth2.ApprovalForce` there. This results in the `prompt=consent` parameter in the authorization request, which _forces_ a consent prompt, even if consent has already been granted. When the user in question is not allowed to consent (which is a common configuration in many organizations), they will be completely blocked from using the app. More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60151790/325697).

Comment: Can you share more details about when you get these errors? As a response to the authorization request (e.g. in a redirect)? As a response to the token request? Or displayed to the user in the sign-in page? How often do you see this?

Comment: I get this error in oauth2 callback during the exchange of a code to a token.

Comment: I don't get any consent-related errors so I doubt it has something to do with it.

Comment: Great job troubleshooting, glad you found the solution, and thank you for sharing. My point about `ApprovalForce` is that you shouldn't be using this, regardless of the issue you were experiencing.

Comment: I upvoted your last comment but later found out that you actually need `ApprovalForce` in case you change permissions requested by your app, so, I think it's always preferable to always have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue caused by the extra headers. Normally it should be only `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header but as you can see above there are extra headers including `Content-Encoding: gzip` which probably causes the issues. These headers added after I connect Microsoft account via oauth2, more specifically is because I use microsoft graph sdk (github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go) after acquiring the token. This SDK implements `RoundTripper` interface that eventually adds extra headers.

Submitted the issue to graph sdk https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go/issues/91

Answer (score -1):

I think second error refers to the ***grant_type*** missing in the config

```
grant_type:authorization_code, 
code: {code you got from the authorization step}, 
client_secret: ****
```

Other way of accessing the OAuth 2.0 Token, Please refer this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token-with-a-certificate-credential)

Comment: If you look up `oauth2Config.Exchange` method you'll see it actually sets it up first thing